# Riemann integrable function with floor function and characteristic function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Hellow, I have a problem with this exercise:

For nonzero real constants $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n$. Let $f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n c_j\lfloor x\rfloor \chi_{[j,j+1)}(x)$, where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer function and $\chi$ denotes the characteristic function on $\mathbb{R}$. Is $f$ Riemann integrable on $\mathbb{R}$? Carefully justify the position taken; if yes, find the value of integral.

I don't understand the question because I just know the definition of riemann integral function in a interval $[a,b]$. What is the definition of Riemann integral function in $\mathbb{R}$?

Thanks.

Comment: For example, notice that if we take $\delta=\frac{1}{2}$, then $f$ is constant on the closed interval $I_j=[j, j+1-\delta]$ and so $\sup_{x \in I_j} f(x)=\inf_{x \in I_j} f(x)=jc_j$ ( $j=1,2, \ldots, n$).

Comment: If there is some detail in my answer that seems unclear or you are unaware that $f$ is Riemann integrable iff $f$ is Darboux integrable, then feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Set $D=\max\{1,|2c_2-c_1|, |3c_3-2c_2|,\ldots, |nc_n-(n-1)c_{n-1}|\}$, and select $\delta = \min \left\{1, \frac{\varepsilon}{Dn} \right\}$. Now we may notice that for every subdivision $P$ of the interval $[1, n+1]$ with mesh less than $\delta$ we have
\begin{aligned} U(P,f)-L(P,f)&<D(n-1)\delta \\& < \varepsilon.
\end{aligned}
Hence we have shown that $\underline {\int_1^{n+1}} f \left({x}\right) d x = \overline {\int_1^{n+1}} f \left({x}\right) d x$, and so $f$ is Darboux integrable over $[1, n+1]$.